# How I get the value from a dictionary if the key from all keys are the same?

Tags: python, django, list, django-models, django-queryset

I want all values from a dictionary, but I have for each value the same key. It is possible to get the values in a separately empty list?

```
dic = QuesModel.objects.values("ans").distinct()
print(dic) 

""" 
Output :
< QuerySet [
{'ans': 'antwort1'}, 
{'ans': 'answer2'}, 
{'ans': 'besitzt als Modelle elemente verschiedene Ereignistypen.'}, {'ans': 'als Nachrichten und Datenobjekte e dargestellt.'}, 
{'ans': '2 ist eine rationale Zahl'}, 
{'ans': 'x hat den Wert 55'}, 
{'ans': ''}]>
"""
```

and I want to get the values from dic in a list, like:

```
for key, values in dic.items():
```

but it is not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do the following:

```py
dic1 = list(QuesModel.objects.values("ans").distinct())
answers = [i['ans'] for i in dic1]
print(answers)
```

> **Note:** Models in Django don't require model to be the suffix, so it is better to name it as `Ques` only or `Question`.

Comment: values_list avoids need for extra comprehension

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes you are right, I know and I was also adding the `values_list` but just some seconds ago, sir Willem posted Answer, then I provided this approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can work with [**`.values_list(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead:

```
QuesModel.objects.values_list('ans', flat=True).distinct()
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `…Model` suffix. Therefore it might be better to rename <s>`QuesModel`</s> to `Question`.